# MVC Url.Action renders URL parameters different in the server than in local

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, web

**The situation**

I am using MVC3 and have the same exact copy of my application in two places: my local IIS and a remote server IIS.

I have a view **A** that renders another partial view **B** using `Html.RenderAction`. Then, view B has an ajax POST set on a click event with the url generated by `Url.Action`.
That Url has two route parameters `"lol"` and `"woot"`.

Here it goes:

- View A

  ```
  @{ Html.RenderAction('MyAction'); }
  ```
- View B

  ```
  $('#NiceButton').on('click', function() {
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "@Url.Action("AwesomeAction", "SuperController", ViewContext.RouteData.Values)",
          data: {
              someArray: someDataArray
          }
      }).done(function() {
          // Some beautiful actions go here
      });
  });
  ```
- Global.asax

  ```
  public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
  {
      routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

      routes.MapRoute(
          "SomeRoute1",
          "SomeRoute1/{p1}/{p2}",
          new {controller = "Controller1", action = "Action1", p1 = UrlParameter.Optional, p2 = UrlParameter.Optional}
          );

      routes.MapRoute(
          "SomeRoute2",
          "SomeRoute2/{p1}/{p2}/{p3}/{p4}",
          new {controller = "Controller2", action = "Action1", p1 = UrlParameter.Optional, p2 = UrlParameter.Optional, p3 = UrlParameter.Optional, p4 = UrlParameter.Optional}
          );

      routes.MapRoute(
          "SomeRoute3",
          "SomeRoute3/{p1}/{p2}",
          new {controller = "Controller3", action = "Action1", p1 = UrlParameter.Optional, p2 = UrlParameter.Optional}
          );

      routes.MapRoute(
          "Actions",
          "{controller}/{action}/{p1}/{p2}/{p3}/{p4}",
          new { controller = "Home", action = "Home", p1 = UrlParameter.Optional, p2 = UrlParameter.Optional, p3 = UrlParameter.Optional, p4 = UrlParameter.Optional}
      );

      routes.MapRoute(
          "Default",
          "{controller}/{action}",
          new { controller = "Home", action = "Home" }
      );
  }
  ```

**The problem**

The URL rendered by Url.Action is different in both servers.

My IIS server renders exactly what I want:

```
localhost/application/SuperController/AwesomeAction/lol/woot
```

But the other IIS server renders

```
server/application/SuperController/AwesomeAction?p1=lol&amp;p2=woot
```

**The question**

What am I missing here? Is there any configuration in IIS that would affect the way Url.Action generates the URLs?

Please also note that the second Url is wrong, because it escapes the ampersand symbol, thus when the server receives this, it treats the second parameter key as "amp;p2".

First I thought that maybe the System.Web.Mvc.dll was different but then I also included the same dll in both application bin folders. I mean, both apps are an exact copy in both places.

**EDIT:** Added Global.asax code.

Comment: Could you please show the route configuration?

Comment: Added the route configuration.

Comment: Hmm... this is really weird. It looks like `Default` gets called instead of `Actions`. Have you checked the `RouteData` on your server? You could use [RouteDebugger](http://www.nuget.org/packages/routedebugger/) for this.

Comment: I confirm the Default is being called since I tried removing the Default and renaming the Actions to be the Default instead. In my local, it just worked fine, but in the server it crashed saying it could not find a route to use, meaning it jumped the Default with the parameters for some reason. I am totally confused about why this behaves different in the other server...

I'll try the RouteDebugger right now, thanks for the tip!

Comment: I tried the RouteDebugger. It seems like with it enabled, the Actions route works, but with it disabled, it doesn't. Probably because the catch-all route this dll adds. Anyhow, this confirms the Actions is not being selected for some reason.

Comment: Since your code is the same here and there, only issue might be is either with configuration files, Web.config and mvc version, compare all dll versions

Comment: As far as I could see, Web.config files and dll files are the same in both places. I even remote debugged the server and checked the versions of the dlls loaded at runtime, they are the same:
System.Web.Mvc --> 3.0.20105.0
System.Web.Razor --> 1.0.20105.407
System.Web.Helpers --> 1.0.20105.407
System.Web.WebPages --> 1.0.20105.407
System.Web.WebPages.Razor --> 1.0.20105.407

Comment: what about debug=true attribute in ur web.config?

Comment: Global.asax settings can be overriden by IIS. Double-check routing for your application in IIS config

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using @url.action directly, use the url i.e. `../Controller/view?parameter`.

You have to put `../` before the controller; that will solve the problem.